# Limit of a sequence of measurable function.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

We know that for a nonnegative measurable function $f$ defined from some measure space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ to $\mathbb{R}$, the integration of $f$ is defined as:
$$\int f= \sup\{\int g:g\ \text{is simple and nonnegative and } g\leq f\}$$
So we can find a sequence $\{\int g_n\}$ in the set at left hand side such that $\int g_n\rightarrow \int f$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$. Let
$$h_n= \max\{g_j:1\leq j\leq n\}$$
Show that $h_n$ increases to $f$ a.e. $(\mu)$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: Please Sir can I have more $\sup$?

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to put it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $0 \le g_n(x) \le h_n(x) \le h_{n+1}(x) \le f(x)$ for all $n,x$.

Hence $0 \le \int g_n \le \int h_n \le \int f$.

Since $h_n$ is non decreasing, we can let $h (x) = \lim_n h_n(x)$.

The monotone convergence theorem shows that $\int h_n \to \int h$ and hence
$\int h = \int f$ from which we have $\int (f-h) = 0$. Since $f(x)-h(x) \ge 0$,
we get $f(x) = h(x)$ ae. $x$ [$\mu$].

Comment: Is not it '$0 \le \int g_n \le \int h_n \le\int f$ in the second line?

Comment: @B.Reddy: Good catch :-).

Comment: @Bungo: Yes, I will add that...

Comment: @ copper.hat Actually the problem above, occurred to me in very elementary level. That is just after the definition. I need to show the equivalence of two definitions. One involves the $Supremum$ conception and another is just the limit of any nondecreasing nonnegative sequence of function. May I ask for a solution which does not involve the Monoton convergence theorem, please?

Comment: @B.Reddy: Actually, it doesn't need the monotone convergence theorem, I was lazy: Note that we have $h_n(x) \le h(x) \le f(x)$ hence $ \int h_n \le \int h \le \int f$. Since $\int g_n \to \int f$, we have $\int h = \int f$. THe rest of the argument remains the same.

Comment: Should be $f(x) = h(x)$ a.e. at the end.

Comment: @Bungo: Thanks again. High bug ratio :-(.

Comment: Not excessively high for a Saturday evening :-)

Comment: @Bungo: I'm blaming the white wine :-).